# use of glTexEnvi function in cocos2d-x

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-x

in cocos2d-x,
I want use opengl texture environment functions. 
ex)glTexEnvi function like this.

```
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB, GL_ADD);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_RGB, GL_PREVIOUS);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC1_RGB, GL_TEXTURE);
```

but, the code makes errors. 
And I can not find the functions and its parameters in cocos2d-x api list.

Comment: "makes errors" - knowing that would help your case

Answer (score 0):

Add OpenGLES to your project. For example,you should add `OpenGLES.framework` to your project if you're coding on iOS platform.

Comment: added it, but makes same compile errors. should I have include some header files?

Comment: anyway it's cocos2d-x not cocos2d. ^^;

Comment: @JinbomHeo android platform? this may help you http://cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/12563

Comment: thanks for your help. But, I think it's not platform dependent problem. Compile doesn't work properly.